# Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. JEST tests

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a problem with JEST tests. I want to test a function but I get an
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSD2d.png).

I want to extract the nearest next date from the date array

```
import { selectLocalizationLanguage } from "domain/localization/localizationSlice";
import { useAppSelector } from "domain/storeHooks";

export function findNextClosestDate(
  array: string[] | undefined,
  target: Date
): string | undefined {
  const language = useAppSelector(selectLocalizationLanguage);
  const targetDate = target.getTime();

  if (!array) return undefined;

  const closestDateFromArray = array.reduce(
    (accumulator: string | undefined, currentValue: string) => {
      const currentValueTime = new Date(currentValue).getTime();
      const accumulatedTime = accumulator && new Date(accumulator).getTime();
      if (
        currentValueTime > targetDate &&
        (!accumulatedTime || currentValueTime < accumulatedTime)
      ) {
        return currentValue;
      }
      return accumulator;
    },
    undefined
  );

  return closestDateFromArray
    ? new Date(closestDateFromArray).toLocaleString(`${language}`, {
        month: "long",
        day: "numeric",
      })
    : undefined;
}
```

Jest test:

```
import { findNextClosestDate } from "./findNextClosestDate";

describe("findNextClosestDate", () => {
  it("return correct closest next date", () => {
    const array = [
      "2022-06-20 08:40:00",
      "2022-06-01 11:08:00",
      "2022-06-08 10:48:00",
      "2022-05-03 08:03:00",
      "2022-05-01 09:58:00",
      "2022-06-19 08:41:00",
    ];
    const target = new Date("2022-05-24 12:04:00");
    const expected = "June 1";
    expect(findNextClosestDate(array, target)).toEqual(expected);
  });
});
```

Where am I making a mistake? I was looking for a solution to this problem but couldn't find the answer.

Comment: add some code for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in useAppSelector (redux toolkit).
Pass props to the function, not get the data in it ;)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).